# Issue adding a value to an object through f.check_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form to submit a new object from my model into my rails app. In this form I have 5 checkboxes where a user can specify a certain 'category' of that new object.

I'm using acts_as_taggable and I [have tried](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#usage) with this snippet that basically if the user checks the box it would add a new value (tag) to the Hack.

```
          <div>
            <%= f.label :retention, :class => 'w-form-label button smalltaghack yellow' %>
            <%= f.check_box :tag_list.add ('Retention') %> 
          </div>
```

But this is returning a **undefined method `add' for :tag_list:Symbol** and I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of any other answers, let me explain why the error will be occurring.

The problem is you're calling `:tag_list.add`

Why are you calling this? The `:tag_list` reference is a *symbol* - it has no functionality; just a way to denote a type of data to be stored in your application.

--

[**MVC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

[image]

I would highly recommend reviewing what you're trying to achieve - especially considering that the MVC programming pattern essentially dictates that any logic for your data should occur within your controller

The job of the view / form is to essentially take the data you have & send it into your controllers / application. This means you shouldn't be using any data-centric functionality on the front-end - it should be in the backend only.

Comment: Thanks Rich. If I'm not wrong,  I should call something in <%= f.check_box :tagretention %> and then in my controller do a def tagretention something end that would tell my controller everytime this checkbox is marked, assign a certain tag. Instead of doing all this stuff directly in the view. Why to do this through the controller and not from the Helper?

Comment: You can do it through a helper if you want - I was just stipulating you should not do it in your form. Your form is really just there to pass data through to your controller; everything else is secondary :)